# curl with large connect-timeout

Tags: curl, connection-timeout

Does curl have a maximum connect-timeout?

```
$ time curl https://google.com:81 --connect-timeout 6000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:400b:80b::1004: Network is unreachable

real    23m19.547s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.020s
```

I was expecting 100 minutes

Comment: Note: I get the same 23.195s timeout when I add on --max-time 6000